# How to get login user's of facebook user acces token and save in mysql

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a code in which i want to get the all data of the login but for that i want the user access token of all users which can login in my project

please help me for that

Thanking you

Comment: which api yor are using for facbook menas JavaScript cpde or php code. have you created app on facebook?

Comment: Php sdk api m first do user login at that time i get name id and other info of user but that time i want user acces token of login user also

Comment: can you please provide response array of facebook which you getting.

Comment: ya sure i get the profile info in array and if i put the key for account and acces they dont get any response

Comment: please visit this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887504/facebook-php-sdk-how-to-get-access-token may it helps you.

Comment: can you provide me a dummy zip or which can get the login user access token